# 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC while reading data form Excel using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, excel-interop

I am new to C# I have written the following code to read the Excel from C# and it is throwing an error while reading the cells.

Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BasicFramework.DatabankController
{
    public class DatabankController<K,V> : Dictionary<K,V>
    {

        public static Dictionary<String, String> storeValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        private static List<DatabankController<String, String>> singleton = null;
        private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myWorkBook;
        private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets myWorkSheets;
        private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
        private DatabankController()
        {

        }
        public static List<DatabankController<String, String>> getInstance(String fileName, String sheetName)
        {
            if (singleton == null)
            {
                singleton = data(fileName, sheetName);

            }
            return singleton;
        }
        private static List<DatabankController<String, String>> data(String filepath, String sheetName)
        {
            List<DatabankController<String, String>> mydata = new List<DatabankController<String,String>>();
            excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            string projectPath = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).FullName;
            if (projectPath.Contains("bin"))
            {
                projectPath = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
            }
            string xmlfilepath = projectPath + "\\BasicFramework\\"+filepath+".xlsx";

            myWorkBook = excel.Workbooks.Open(xmlfilepath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            myWorkSheets = myWorkBook.Worksheets;

            Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myWorkSheets.get_Item(sheetName);
            int columnCount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
            int rowCount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                DatabankController<String, String> currentHash = new DatabankController<string, string>();
                for(int j = 0;j<= columnCount;j++)
                {
                        if(i>0)
                            currentHash.Add((String)((Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j]).ToString(), (String)((Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[i,j]).ToString());
                }
                mydata.Add(currentHash);
            }

            myWorkBook.Close();
            myWorkBook = null;
            excel.Quit();
            excel = null;
            return mydata;
        }
        public static DatabankController<String, String> getdataBankCounterRecord(String FileName,String SheetName,String rule)
        {
            List<DatabankController<String, String>> getValue = getInstance(FileName,SheetName);
            DatabankController<String, String> dbcontroller = null;
            bool flag = false;
            int i = 0;
            foreach(DatabankController<String, String> h in  getValue)
            {
                foreach (String h1 in h.Keys.ToArray())
                {
                    if (h[h1].Contains(rule))
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                if (flag == true)
                {
                    dbcontroller = getValue[i];
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return dbcontroller;
        }
    }
}
```

Exactly in the following line its throwing the error.My Excel sheet is being opened with the open() method but after that when it is going to read the data its failing. Can anyone help me on this please.

```
currentHash.Add((String)((Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j]).ToString(), (String)((Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[i,j]).ToString());
```

Comment: Try after adding null checks to the line in question; I suspect the odd behaviour linked with Null values. Please post your results above.

Comment: @vCillusion it is throwing the same exception at null check as well in this way I have kept the null chek  if(i>0&&(xlWorksheet.Cells[i,j]!=null))

Comment: Do remember to do < columnCount not <=  .. if there are 52 columns 0-51 .. not 0-52

Comment: @BugFinder I tried by removing= and kept only < but no luck found

Comment: What is the value of i and j, and your counts at the time of barf